# What is the return type I should use for sending an array of structs over QDBus?

Tags: c++, qt, struct

I have a struct of two strings and an int:

```
struct dirList
{
    QString fileName;
    QString source;
    int type;
};
```

The goal is to send an array of structs listing the contents of a directory over QDBus to a KIO slave to read the contents and prepare UDS Entries. My function for sending the list looks like this:

```
QList<StashNotifier::dirList> StashNotifier::fileList(const QString &path) //forwards list over QDBus to the KIO slave
{
    QList<dirList> contents;
    dirList item;
    StashFileSystem::StashNodeData node = fileSystem->findNode(path);
    for (auto it = node.children->begin(); it != node.children->end(); it++) {
        item.fileName = it.key();
        item.source = it.value().source;
        item.type = (int) it.value().type;
        contents.append(item);
    }
    return contents;
}
```

However, it is mentioned in the Qt documentation that using QList [is not supported](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbustypesystem.html) for QDBus. Therefore, what is the correct return type for this function to work? I have also tried editing the .xml file generated by qdbuscpp2xml by hand to make it look like this:

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.kde.kio.StashNotifier">
    <signal name="listChanged">
    </signal>
    <method name="addPath">
      <arg name="path" type="s" direction="in"/>
      <arg name="currentDir" type="s" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <method name="removePath">
      <arg name="path" type="s" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <method name="fileList">
      <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="QList<dirList>"/>
      <arg name="path" type="s" direction="in"/>
      <arg name="contents" type="a(ssi)" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

But this too fails, and qdbusxml2cpp doesn't recognize the custom type replacing the return type with void instead. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: It's just `QList<QVariant>` that is no allowed, because it makes no sense in the DBus type system. The problem I see is that the `dirList` is a custom type. It probably needs `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and marshalling functions like in: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusargument.html#details